# JMeter simulate 1000 users simultaneously for 1 minute

Tags: java, jmeter

I've been looking around, but it's still not clear to me how to set up JMeter to simulate 1000 concurrent users for one minute.

How should the threads, Ramp-up and Duration be configured?

I hope I was clear in the request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going for the following [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) setup:

[image]

Explanation:

1. Number of threads - `1000` as this is how many users you need to have
2. Ramp-up period. It's better to increase the load gradually, this way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with other metrics and KPIs. As per JMeter Documentation

   > The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
   >
   > Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
   >
   > Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

   in your case given the short test duration it makes sense to increase the load for first 30 seconds and the last 30 seconds will be "plateau"
3. Loop Count: you need to give JMeter sufficient amount of iterations because if a thread finish samplers execution and there are no more loops to iterate the thread will be shut down and [the actual load may be lower](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected).
4. Duration is `60` seconds

Answer (score 0):

Basically `Number of Threads` determines the concurrency. If you add 100 threads Jmeter will spin up 100 concurrent threads. Then you can tell Jmeter how this max should be reached. If you add a `Ramp Up Period` the threads will be gradually created within the configured time period. For example, if you configure 100 threads and 10 seconds ramp-up time. At the end of the 10th second, Jemeter will make sure all 100 threads are running. We can say each second Jmeter will create 10 threads. This option is useful if you don't want to generate sudden spikes of load, say you want to warmup the server and then do your load/perf test then you can use the ramp-up time.